# WebIDE not connecting to Safari iOS (Handler function DebuggerClient.requester request callback threw an exception)

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

I've an iPhone 4, connected via USB to a Linux host (Mint 17) to iPhone 4 running iOS 7 and dev tools on. I'm running developer edition and ios-webkit-debug-proxy to expose the iOS debugger.

localhost:9222 looks like:
[image: screenshot of localhost:9222]

Log I'm getting when spanner > Web IDE, Select runtime > Safari on iOS:

```
console.log: Connection status changed: connecting
console.error: 

Handler function DebuggerClient.requester request callback threw an exception: Error: 'getAll' request packet has no destination.
Stack: DebuggerClient.prototype.request@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm:667:1
AppActorFront.prototype.watchApps@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/app-actor-front.js:570:35
exports.AppManager.onConnectionChanged/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource:///modules/devtools/webide/app-manager.js:112:9
DebuggerClient.requester/</<@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm:348:9
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:83:14
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:96:9
Request.prototype.emit@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm:1092:29
DebuggerClient.prototype.onPacket/<@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm:931:9
resolve@resource://gre/modules/devtools/deprecated-sync-thenables.js:40:40
then@resource://gre/modules/devtools/deprecated-sync-thenables.js:20:43
then@resource://gre/modules/devtools/deprecated-sync-thenables.js:58:9
DebuggerClient.prototype.onPacket@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm:869:1
LocalDebuggerTransport.prototype.send/<@resource://gre/modules/devtools/dbg-client.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/transport/transport.js:545:11
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:83:14
makeInfallible/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/DevToolsUtils.js:83:14
Line: 667, column: 0
console.error: 

console.log: Connection status changed: disconnecting
console.log: Connection status changed: disconnected
```

Comment: I think ios-webkit-debug-proxy can only connect with Chrome (webkit debugger)? May be different on Firefox dev-edition.

Comment: It does through Valence https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence

Comment: Bugs for Valence should be logged [here](https://github.com/campd/fxdt-adapters/issues)